# Trig Integration, how did they get this answer?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> Here is the full question for context:

[image]

> And here is the full answer given:

[image]

I don't understand how they go from the first part in the red box to the next, I don't have a clue.

Comment: They took the antiderivative using $u$ substitution $u=\sin x$.

Comment: I have a question, what's with the down votes? What did I do wrong?

Comment: @user3204017, People likely saw that you just posted links to images of your question and decided to downvote based on that. Usually if someone just posts links to images, it's a strong sign that they just took a picture of their homework and posted it here for an answer without trying themselves. For future reference, instead of posting images, you should learn how to [type mathematics on this site with MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It's a show of good faith that you put in some effort.

Comment: @MikePierce Ah okay, fair enough. Though I should say that was only part a of the question. I'll try and learn mathjax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a $u$ substitution where they take $u = \sin(x)$. If $u = \sin(x)$, then $\mathrm{d}u = \cos(x) \;\mathrm{d}x$. So we have
$$\begin{align}
  \int {\sin^{2n}(x)\cos(x)} \;\mathrm{d}x \;\;&=\;\; 
  \int {u^{2n}} \;\mathrm{d}u \\\;\;&=\;\;
  \frac{u^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \;\;=\;\;
  \frac{\sin^{2n+1}(x)}{2n+1}
\end{align}$$